# Python - replace prefix with other substring and add it as suffix

Tags: python, string

Is there any way to do the following transformation to a string:

```
original_str = "CREATE TABLE a.table as SELECT * from b.table"
(...) ??????
final_str = "CREATE TABLE w.table_a as SELECT * from w.table_b"
```

I think that maybe there is some library, like **re**, that can do it, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: ```re```, ```str.replace(...)``` in fact there are dozens of options. Could you show where exactly are you failing with this assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w)\.table')

re.sub(pattern, r'w.table_\1', 'a.table')
re.sub(pattern, r'w.table_\1', 'b.table')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the use case is not any more complicated this might be a simple solution:

```
final_str = original_str
    .replace('a.table', 'w.table_a')
    .replace('b.table', 'w.table_b')
```